# Ayuda, estoy algo confudido con Eslint & PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

como va?

Estoy algo confundido con los PropTypes, estoy probando eslint "para mejorar mi codigo me esta sucediendo esto"

1) De verdad no se que pasa tengo el siguiente props de tipo array me succede esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, me entro la curiosidad de ponerlo de tipo object, succede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tengo configuardo mis propTypes:

```js
 `Menu.propTypes = {
  // dataUser: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  // dataUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dataUser: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.array).isRequired,
  loader_menu: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};`
```

Segun la documentacion de React [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

// An array of a certain type
  optionalArrayOf: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),

// An object with property values of a certain type
  optionalObjectOf: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number),

El codigo funciona, no pero el unico fallo son los proptypes

my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as dataActions from '../../redux/actions/menuActions';
import SpinnerStats from '../../utils/SpinnerStats';

class Menu extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.UserData();
  }

  menu = () => {
    const { dataUser } = this.props;
    const logo = dataUser.country_code;

    if (this.props.loader_menu) {
      return <SpinnerStats />;
    }
    return (
      <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg'>
        <Link to='/' className='navbar-brand'>
          <img
            className='menuCountry'
            src={`https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/${logo}.svg`}
            alt={dataUser.code}
          />{' '}
          Covid 19
        </Link>

        <p>
          En
          {dataUser.country_name}
        </p>

        <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
          <form className='form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 search'>
            <input
              className='form-control mr-sm-2'
              type='search'
              placeholder='Buscar por paises'
              aria-label='Search'
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <div className='lime-header'>{this.menu()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (reducers) => {
  return reducers.menuReducer;
};

Menu.propTypes = {
  // dataUser: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  // dataUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dataUser: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.array).isRequired,
  loader_menu: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dataActions)(Menu);
```

Comment: Hola David. Estas planteando dos preguntas, deberías editar y publicar una pregunta nueva con tu segunda cuestión.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de la estructura de `dataUser` ? Comprueba tambien que no estés mutando el tipo.